Argument of \let has an extra }
I simply want to highlight the title of a subsection with below:
\subsection{\hl{Computation Time}} \label{sec:comp_time}

I added "\usepackage{soul}" at the beginning of the latex file.
But I got an error saying
"Argument of \let has an extra }"
I also tried using
\subsection{\hl{Computation Time}\label{sec:comp_time}}

(not sure which is the correct way)
But still got the same error
I'm very sorry but I do have a messy preamble of packages etc added in the beginning of the file
\documentclass[12pt]{spieman}  % 12pt font required by SPIE;

\usepackage[left, pagewise]{lineno}
\linenumbers

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %unicode support
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{0.7cm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
 \usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage[skip=0pt]{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,fit} %use shapes library if you need ellipse

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsfonts,booktabs,multirow,array,comment}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{color}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{4}
\usepackage{graphbox} 
\newcommand*{\myinclude}[1]{\includegraphics[width=1in, align=m]{#1}}
\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500
\newcommand{\cmt}[1]{{\textcolor{red}{(\emph{#1})}}}
\newcommand{\M}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\newcommand{\V}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{argmax}

\newcommand*{\bigCI}{%
  \mathrel{\text{%
    {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\resizebox{2.25ex}{1.65ex}{$\vDash$}}}%
  }}%
}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\sloppy
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.5}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcommand{\forceindent}{\leavevmode{\parindent=1.5em\indent}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\orderof}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{O}}}
\makeatletter

\makeatother
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{5em}}
\newcommand{\mr}{\mathrm}
\newcommand{\squeezeup}{\vspace{-2.5mm}}
\newcommand{\mb}{\mathbf}
\newcommand{\beq}{\begin{equation}}
\newcommand{\eeq}{\end{equation}}
\newcommand{\bea}{\begin{algorithmic}}
\newcommand{\eea}{\end{algorithmic}}
\renewcommand{\vec}{\mbox{vec}}

\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\NewDocumentCommand{\ceil}{s O{} m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1} % starred
    {\left\lceil#3\right\rceil} % \ceil*[..]{..}
    {#2\lceil#3#2\rceil} % \ceil[..]{..}
}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{soul}

\usepackage{colortbl} % For coloring table cells

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\code}[1]{%
  \texorpdfstring{{\sethlcolor{gray}\hl{\texttt{#1}}}}%
                 {#1}%
}
\soulregister{\code}{1}

\crefname{section}{Â§}{Â§Â§}
\Crefname{section}{Â§}{Â§Â§}
\newcommand\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}

\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}

Not sure if any of the packages result in conflict or any issue I'm having.
Any help is appreciated!
UPDATE:
\colorbox worked for me.
\subsection{\colorbox{yellow}{Computation Time}}


I think you cannot use this in the title of a section - at least without specifying an alternative for the toc/headers etc. most of your preamble is irrelevant and could be removed for the purposes of this question. please delete what isn't necessary. you should also complete your code so we can compile it to reproduce the error. off-topic: your preamble will cause you problems if you do not clean it up. don't load packages multiple times. don't load conflicting packages. do load packages in the correct order. eg. hyperref should be late, but cleveref should be even later.

Why I cannot highlight the title of a section? So how can I do this?

see Werner's answer below ;). you have to provide a non-highlighted alternative for use in those other places, as I said. you can't e.g. have highlighting in the bookmarks and so on.

Your best way around this is to supply separate arguments for the in-text setting of the \section and the floating argument part, even though they may be duplicates.

\documentclass{spieman}
% https://spie.org/conferences-and-exhibitions/future-sensing-technologies/presenters/manuscript-submission-guidelines#_=_

\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}

\section[A section]{A \hl{section}}

\end{document}

In general, sectional headings could be considered fragile as they float to other parts of the document (like the header, or the ToC and PDF bookmarks). Supplying clean textual content via the optional argument often helps clear up these issues.

The error happens when hyperref is trying to make the bookmark.
The fix is simple.
\documentclass{spieman}

\usepackage{soul}

% make hyperref ignore \hl in bookmarks
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\hl=\relax}

\begin{document}

\section{A \hl{section}}

\end{document}


